# How can I visualize the sum of values of 3 months before for each month?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have updated a sample of my data here: [SAMPLE PBIX](https://mega.nz/#!JpUGRazL!xQtE3FBi27CckXE7h_FoMRn8ZpnHUkx_LxVCiG8dwdg)

I need a matrix with customers on rows, date on column and the sum of 3 previous month of test[boolean] for each month.  Do you have an idea? I have tried some measures but power bi does not display anything

My test:

```
sumlast3months =CALCULATE(SUM(data2[BOOLEAN]);DATEADD(TIMELINKTABLE[Date];-3;MONTH))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `DATESINPERIOD`, like this:

```
Sum (Rolling 3 Months) =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( data2[BOOLEAN] ),
    DATESINPERIOD ( TIMELINKTABLE[Date], MAX ( TIMELINKTABLE[Date] ), -3, MONTH )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution

```
sumlast3months = 
var month3=CALCULATE(
SUM(data2[BOOLEAN]);
DATEADD(TIMELINKTABLE[Date];-3;MONTH))
var month2=CALCULATE(
SUM(data2[BOOLEAN]);
DATEADD(TIMELINKTABLE[Date];-2;MONTH))

var month1=CALCULATE(SUM(data2[BOOLEAN]);
DATEADD(TIMELINKTABLE[Date];-2;MONTH))

return
month1+month2+month3
```